# Use C# created DLL in PowerBuilder 12.5.2

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, powerbuilder, password-encryption

I have created a simple C# class library targetting .Net Framework 4.5.2 with one class using Visual Studio 2015 enterprise edition.

**Sample code:**

```
namespace PwdEncryptor
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public string Encrypt (string actualPassword)
        {
           return String.Concat(actualPassword, "Encrypt");
        }
    }
}
```

I want to use this from my powerbuilder code on **another system**.

**Purpose** of doing this is to have common code for encryption of password.

**Problem:**

I used it in my powerbuilder code by declaring in the Global instance variables like this:

Function string Encrypt(string actualPassword) Library "PwdEncryptor.dll"

And in Open event of the application I wrote:

```
string pwd
pwd = Encrypt("XYZ")
```

When I ran the code, I got a message saying **"Unknown function name"**

To overcome this I tried the solution mentioned [here](http://blogs.artinsoft.net/Mrojas/archive/2009/03/03/Calling-NET-from-PowerBuilder.aspx). A small deviation that I took was instead of doing the execution in powerbuilder on the same system I exported the registry which was created & imported to other system where powerbuilder code exists. In this case the error that I got was **Bad runtime function refernce at line  in Open event of Application object.**

Is there a way that I can possibly use the DLL I have created? Am I missing something? Please advise.

Comment: Is the DLL registered on the system which you run your PowerBuilder code?

Comment: @MattBalent: Yes, it is registered in the Registry. It gets registered as a part of the build on my system from the sample solution present in the link I mentioned in the question. FYI, it gets registered under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT. I import this registry & then export it on the system having PowerBuilder code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this.

Instead of exporting the registry from my system & importing it on the system containing powerbuilder code, I should have registered my C# dll using **RegAsm.exe**

Once the DLL is registered, the PowerBuilder code is able to use the C# code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to expose DLL as COM visible. Detailed info at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842017/net-interop-in-powerbuilder?rq=1) and [this other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092553/turn-a-simple-c-sharp-dll-into-a-com-interop-component).

[image: Project properties > Application > Make assembly COM-visible]

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have already made the dll COM visible as suggested in the link I have provided in the question. Maybe you could have a look at the link & then advise if I'm doing anything wrong.